# How to save the UI state of optional GridLayoutManaer RecyclerView in saveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView which uses GridLayoutManager and different adapters upon selected menu item. I want to save the state of last displayed items of the RecyclerView, so that user can see the same upon configuration changes. The UI doesn't have to fall back to the default UI.

Below is my MainActivity which I want to save its UI.

```
@Overrideprotected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mDb = AppDatabase.getInstance(getApplicationContext());    
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.hasExtra("Favourite")){  
      int favouriteMovie = intent.getIntExtra("Favourite", -2);        
       if (favouriteMovie == 1) {        
           loadFavouriteMovie();        
       }    
    }    
    movies = new ArrayList<>();    
    favouriteMovies = new ArrayList<>();    
    mLoadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);    
    mImageGrid = findViewById(R.id.rv_movies);    
    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2);    
    mImageGrid.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);    
    mImageGrid.setHasFixedSize(true);    
    mAdapter = new 
    ImageGridAdapter(this, movies);    
    mImageGrid.setAdapter(mAdapter);    
    DividerItemDecoration decoration = new 
    DividerItemDecoration(this, VERTICAL);    
    mImageGrid.addItemDecoration(decoration);    
    DividerItemDecoration decoration2 = new 
    DividerItemDecoration(this, HORIZONTAL);    
    mImageGrid.addItemDecoration(decoration2);    
    loadMoviesTask();    
    //populateMovieData();
}
    @Overrideprotected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);    
    if ((savedInstanceState != null) && (savedInstanceState.getParcelable(STATE_KEY) != null)){        
        listState = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(STATE_KEY);   
    }
   }
    @Overrideprotected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {    
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);    
        listState = layoutManager.onSaveInstanceState();    
        outState.putParcelable(STATE_KEY, listState);
}
```

I am aware this can be achieved using key and saving it in database and at onCreate, RecyclerView can be generated by querying the database with the saved key, but I don't want to be querying database at every onCreate: I want to have the state saved using onSavedInstanceState.

I have tried with the code above, but the app wouldn't just do what I want.

Comment: Don't apologize for code formatting, fix it. If you don't even bother making your code readable for anyone who tries to help you... why should they bother?

Comment: plz make the code clear to read :-\

Comment: The code is now edited